# Android Studio: NullPointerException with getSupportActionBar()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I want to show an ActionBar in my Activity while only showing a closing symbol. Therefore I used the method getSupportActionBar():

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);
        setTitle("Add Event");
```

But it throws a NullPointerExeption because apparently there's no ActionBar to call:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tutorial/com.example.tutorial.AddEventActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)' on a null object reference
```

In my MainActivity I implemented a Drawer Navigation where I already used a toolbar that works:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;

    // Make sure to be using androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle version.
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // This will display an Up icon (<-), we will replace it with hamburger later
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        // Setup toggle to display hamburger icon with nice animation
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        // Find our drawer view
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
    }
```

How do I fix that? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line :

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

with this line :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add following attribute to your `MainActivity` item under your `ActivityManifest.xml`

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Then try to access it with the `getSupportActionBar()`. With this way you can choose the activities that you don't or do want to include actionbars by using relevant themes. For example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```